# Putty: copy & paste -> preserve blanks

Tags: putty

we want to switch to Putty at work, but we have one big problem: in error situations we have to copy some lines from our logfile (using less/vi and mouse copy & paste). These lines can be 32 KB long and contain several blanks, the blanks need to be preserved. Unfortunately, if the copied content is wrapped because it doesn't fit in one line in the window, Putty seems to replace the trailing blanks with a newline character.

e.g. if we have the line (with trailing spaces that need to be preserved -> you see the trailing spaces if you select the example):

```
LINE START, WINDOW IS 80 CHARACTERS WIDTH, BUT LINE IS 32KB                    
  SO LINE IS WRAPPED IN THE PUTTY WINDOW                                       
      THE TRAILING SPACES NEED TO BE PRESERVED....                             
      BUT USING PUTTYS COPY & PASTE, PUTTY REPLACES SPACE CHARACTERS BY NEWLINE
                                                                ...LINE END
```

and we copy & paste, we get (select second example):

```
LINE START, WINDOW IS 80 CHARACTERS WIDTH, BUT LINE IS 32KB
  SO LINE IS WRAPPED IN THE PUTTY WINDOW
      THE TRAILING SPACES NEED TO BE PRESERVED....
      BUT USING PUTTYS COPY & PASTE, PUTTY REPLACES SPACE CHARACTERS BY NEWLINE
                                                                ...LINE END
```

Putty cuts the trailing spaces and inserts a newline character. Can this behaviour be configured/changed in Putty?

Thank you,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

I have used non-breaking spaces to retain trailing whitespace when copying/pasting from PuTTY. My application was ssh-ing into a linux box and copying/pasting some code using the Bourne shell, so I don't know how widely this will work in other environments.

To insert a non-breaking space, hold the Alt key and type 255, then release the Alt key. The following example can be used for testing. For some reason, the code doesn't retain the non-breaking space when I copy/paste directly from this webpage, so you will need to test it this way:

a. Copy/paste the code below into notepad

b. Delete the space in blank=" "

c. Insert a non-breaking space with Alt+255

d. Copy/paste the code into PuTTY

e. Copy/paste the output back into notepad to view results

**CODE**

```
# non-breaking space, Alt+255
blank=" "
# regular space
space=" "

echo "
blank:$blank
space:$space
"
```

Which outputs a trailing space for the $blank var, but not for the $space var.

**OUTPUT**

```
blank: 
space:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Putty can do it but in my case (putty working on redhat open client) I converted source files to unix format (dos2unix command).
Now pasting works fine.